# Painting over a Quad

Tags: unity

So I want to create a quad as a base for my game where I will put stuff on it ( trees rocks buildings etc ) ..Now how can I paint over the quad and put stuff on it?...Is it possible?

I wanted to use a terrain at first but I have been told there will performance issues and a quad would be a better choice. All sprites are going to be static too.

Comment: You can put stuff on it sure, but as far as painting, you may just want to 'paint' a texture in photoshop and then import it as a texture and lay it on the quad.

Comment: @n_palum so can I lay multiple textures on a quad?

Comment: You would have to use a project to do so but yes - https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Projector.html

Comment: You put stuff on it by...putting stuff on it. There's really no magic trick here. You take the thing you want to put on top of the quad (say, a mesh or a sprite), drag it from your assets folder into the scene view, and position it on top of the quad. Have you run into any particular difficulty doing this?